# Load object data from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following class:

```
[Serializable]

public class SerialAssassin
{
    public Hero hero;
    public Point heroPB;
    public Boss boss;
    public Point bossPB;
    public Attack attack;
    public Point attackPB;
    public HPMeter bossHP;
    public Point bossHPPB;
    public PPMeter heroPP;
    public Point heroPPPB;

    public Rectangle bossRect;
    public Rectangle attackRect;

    public int heroState;
    public int stepRate;
    public int attackDirection;
    public int attackLoop;
    public int contadorPaso;
    public int contadorPasoBoss;
    public int bossTop, bossLeft;
    public int bossState;
    public int bossHealth;
    public int bossHPCap;
    public int opa;
    public int battlesWon;
    public int mainBossCounter;
    public int ppleft;
    public bool paso;
    public bool inStadium;
    public bool fading;
    public bool fightingMainBoss;
    public bool fainted;
    public string currentPokemon;
}
```

I'm having problems reading the data from the XML, which was written as follows:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerialAssassin));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Resources\saveState.xml");
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, serial);
textWriter.Close();
```

From there, I don't quite know how to read the data. Plus the fact that the XML doesn't serialize the objects of Hero, Boss, Attack, HPMeter, PPMeter.

Hero class:

```
public class Hero
    {

        int state = 0;
        int x, y;
        string path;
        Image img;


        //methods
    }
```

I'd be grateful if you would be so kind as to explain to me how to load those objects/primitives and then use them.

Comment: Does the objects not serialized have the [Serializable] attribute?

Comment: If you haven't receive the answer you expect do not post another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870879/serialize-a-form-along-with-all-its-data-in-c-sharp). Try updating you previous one in a way somebody can answer it as expected.

Comment: @MattiasJosefsson Yes, they are serializable, but they are just <hero /> or <boss /> in the saved file.

Comment: @Fiire Do your `Hero` and `Boss` classes have public properties? Perhaps you can post one for us here.

Comment: @Fiire Thanks for posting the `Hero` class. Check the edit on my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>IIRC, the `XmlSerializer` checks for properties, not fields.</strike> (I think it can use public fields, but you really ought to switch to properties anyway) In addition, classes do *not* need to be marked as `Serializable`. (`Serializable` is used for others such as binary and SOAP serializers)

Replace your fields with properties with public getters and setters. In addition, make sure your other classes (such as `Hero`, `Point`, `Boss`) are all also serializable according to `XmlSerializer`'s rules:

```
public class SerialAssassin
{
    public Hero hero { get; set; }
    public Point heroPB { get; set; }
    public Boss boss { get; set; }
    public int heroState { get; set; }
    ...
```

To deserialize, use its `Deserialize` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize.aspx):

```
Stream xmlInputStream = ... //get your file stream, or TextReader, or XmlReader
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerialAssassin));
SerialAssassin assassin = (SerialAssassin)deserializer.Deserialize(xmlInputStream)
```

EDIT: Looking at your sample `Hero` class, it's not serializing any of its values because you have declared them all to be private. Make them public instead.

```
public class Hero
{
    public int state {get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Image img { get; set; }
}
```

I suspect that `Image` will *not* be serializable, so you may want to store the image's file path (or some other identifying information) so you can save/load it. `[XmlIgnore]` will instruct the `XmlSerializer` to ignore that property so it doesn't fail during serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Silly me, it isn't enough to make the class public? I think that Image is actually serializable (msdn). EDIT: never mind. It can't be serialized.

Comment: @Fiire No. If you do not explicitly declare the visibility of a class's member, it will always default to `private`; it does not inherit the visibility of the class it's declared on.

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerialAssassin));
SerialAssassin assassin;

using(var reader = File.OpenText(@"..\..\Resources\saveState.xml"))
{
   assassin = (SerialAssassin)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```